# Concante Show time in one cell

Tags: excel

HI I have list of Show timings in 24 hrs format with me. I am trying to concanate them in one cell. but the time format is lost . What would be best method to have it in one cell without changing the format?

Answer (score 0):

This will concatenate the times with format. Admittedly, it is not the best approach for a large range since you need to type in each cell:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss;@")," ",TEXT(A2,"[h]:mm:ss;@"))
```